# How to capture a value after a special character with regex?

Tags: regex

I need to extract the `CN` value from this string:

`CN=John Doe,OU=Testing,OU=Dev Workspace,OU=Product Domain,DC=it,DC=co`

In this example, the value I'm after in John Doe.

`(CN=)\w+\s\w+` will match `CN=John Doe`
`(?<=CN=)[^,]+` will match John Doe, but I don't think the parser will support positive lookbehinds.
`CN=([^,]+)` will match `CN=John Doe` but `John Doe` will be in the first group.

Comment: What is the tool or language? If it is supported you might use `\K` like `\bCN=\K[^,]+`

Comment: @Thefourthbird This will be in PingFederate to map some Active Directory attributes in a single-sign on configuration.

Comment: To add to that, I believe Ping leverages Java

Comment: Java does support a lookbehind. But you tried `(?<=CN=)[^,]+` and it failed? Did you get an error message?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. I am meeting with our SSO engineer to give it a try later this week. I was told that some parsers don't support lookbehind, so I was under the impression it wouldn't be the language, rather the application (i.e. Ping).

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
CN=([^,]+)
```

And use the first capture group. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/U0ANLW/1).

Comment: I would like to. However, I have yet to figure out how to return the group 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a long shot, but maybe just give a try to `\K` (Keep Out) to see if that might work, I doubt that though:

```
CN=\K([^,]+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxU8qn/1/)

Comment: I'll give it a try on Friday and will report back.